# Conformal mapping between a square and a unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am in need of a specific (simple, if possible) complex bijection mapping that would map a square onto the unit disk, including an explanation/examination of "why it works". I need it as an example showing the Riemann theorem in practice, yet despite thinking/trying and searching online, I cannot come up with a good idea. If possible, additional explanation of how the mapping is constructed/which way of thinking about it yields the result would be very much appreciated, so that I can understand how these problems can be approached on a general basis. Thank you kindly.

edit: I've found this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159067/schwarz-christoffel-maps-from-unit-disk-to-regular-polygons-visualization; if I plug in n = 4 here, would I get what I'm looking for, and if yes, how do I prove "it works", that is, that it is a bijection, conformal, and that it indeed maps the unit disk onto a square?

Also a note: I am a beginner with Complex Analysis, so apologies if these questions are trivial.

Comment: See [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping)

Comment: Note also that these are as nice as you get, seeing as any two conformal maps from $\mathbb{D}$ to any domain are related via pre-composition by a Möbius transform.

Comment: As for how they're constructed, it's not too hard to see with the integral representation in the half-plane, that your map $t\mapsto \int_0^t \frac{K}{(x-a)^{1/2}(x-b)^{1/2}(x-c)^{1/2}(x-d)^{1/2}}\textrm{d}x$ maps real intervals to straight lines between the four points $a,b,c,d,$ where the changing sign under the square root causes the map to take a turn of $\pi/2$.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the Schwartz-Christoffel mapping as described in the wikipedia link is a transformation from the upper half plane onto a polygon? I need a transformation that maps a square onto the unit disk. Also apologies, but I am a complete beginner with Complex Analysis, so I'd appreciate an ELI5 approach if anyone has the patience/time.

Comment: A conformal mapping preserves angles of intersection.  That's going to be hard for the intersection of the sides of the square.

Comment: @AAL147 You can go from the disk to the half-plane via the inverse Cayley transform $-i\frac{z+i}{z-1}$. It's not completely straightforward to see that the Schwarz-Christoffel map (on the half-plane) really is conformal. It's clear enough that it maps the real line to a rectangle, but then the only argument I know for it actually being injective involves a tedious application of the residue theorem.

Comment: And I somewhat doubt that the inverse map has a nice description.

Comment: The Schwartz-Christoffel formula for the mapping from the unit disk to a polygon is formally the same as for the mapping from the upper half-plane to a polygon (with points taken on the unit circle instead of on the real line). For a square, it gives the elliptic integral of the first kind with $m = -1$. The elliptic sine $\operatorname {sn}(z \mid -1)$ maps $\left| \operatorname {Re} z \right| + \left| \operatorname {Im} z \right| < K(-1)$ to the unit disk.